# Which framework / CMS to choose for a website?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I want to create a website with a very large database, so if you type an ID or name of product you can get its info and also there are some other functions like look where you can find this product etc. So there will be many large tables that are connected to each other, and a website that always works with them.

So I wanted to ask how should I create this website, can I manage it with a CMS (which would be the best option) or I should use framework (PHP-based) or start from scratch. Because I am afraid if I use a CMS then it will affect website speed, although it's only my guess.

I have some experience with Drupal so possibly someone knows whether this kind of websites can be written in it. Anyway any advice for me is important. Thank you in advance!

Konstantins

Comment: Given the detailled functional specification you provided, which CMS you use will not affect performance

Comment: "what is the best cms/framework" - answer will vary from person to person. It'l initiate a debate.

Comment: For anyone wondering which framework to choose, read and watch Uncle Bob: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853233/1614973

Answer (score 1):

If you already have experience with Drupal I'd suggest to use that. There are many ways to optimize the speed of your data access. My best guess is that you look at Solr to speed up data-indexing; http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

There is also a Drupal module available for that to get you up and running;
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr

But if time is not an issue, I'd suggest to look into some frameworks. At the moment I think Symfony 2 will do the job just fine.
http://symfony.com/